# How to implement responsive card-columns in less

Tags: sass, less, twitter-bootstrap-4

The bootstrap docs gives this to make card columns responsive in SASS:

```
  .card-columns {
    @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

However, I have a LESS version of bootstrap 4 in my website.

How do I write the above is less syntax?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
@media (min-width: 544px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1.25rem; }
    .card-columns .card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 3; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 4; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-columns {
    column-count: 5; } }
```